# In ruby, how can I convert a function's response/results into an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, function, store

In ruby, how can I convert a function response into array for later usage?

```
array = []
def function (subject1)
    results = client.get('/subjects', :genre => subject1)
    results.each { |r| puts r.title }
    array << r.title
end

function(subject1)
```

My code looks like something similar above. My results however are never stored. Please and thanks for your help :)

Comment: What does `results = client.get(...)` return into `results`? Is it already an array? It's at least enumerable, since you're doing `results.each...`

Comment: try `results.map(&:title)` as the last line in place of `...each` and `array <<...` this will return an `Array` of all `titles` from `results` so really it could be 1 line `client.get('/subjects', :genre => subject1).map(&:title)` will have the same result. The you just store it in a variable `a = function(subject1)`

Comment: yes, client.get('...') turn into real results that I limit by choosing a subject in the genre. @lurker

Comment: ok, i'm going to try it now @engineersmnky

Comment: results.each { |r| array << r.title } is what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each method will iterate through every element whereas map would return an array in itself.

```
def function(subject1)
    results = client.get('/subjects', :genre => subject1)
    results.map { |r| r.title }
end

function(subject1)
```

Comment: so to call on the array later i would just put results.map ?

Comment: you can save the result to a variable like so ``response = function(subject1)``

Answer (score 1):

"My results however are never stored" - store the result then:

```
result = function(subject1)
```

Answer (score -2):

Or you can make array a global var

```
$array = []
def function (subject1)
  results = client.get('/subjects', :genre => subject1)
  results.each { |r| $array << r.title }
end

function(subject1)
```

Or you can do this

```
array = []
def function (subject1)
  results = client.get('/subjects', :genre => subject1)
  results.each { |r| puts r.title }
end

array = function(subject1)
```